# Salesforce Apex: Count Number of Line Breaks in Text Field

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code, soql, apex

I'd like to create a trigger and/or class that counts the number of line break in a longtext field in Salesforce.com.

Will this logic work if I change the debug message to instead write the commentsLength to a custom field?

```
public with sharing class TaskCommentsCount {
Integer commentsLength = 0;

for(Task t : [Select Comments From Task]){
List<String> lines = t.Comments.split('\n');
commentsLength += lines.size();
}

system.debug('Comments lines: ' + commentsLength);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How old your trigger / class is? Some time this year (Spring'13 release?) The `String` class received major upgrade and we have now the `countMatches()` method.

Maybe you just need to upgrade the API version to be able to use it in your trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you'd change this logic to work in a Trigger.

Logically, your splitting should work, but you'll need to rearchitect it slightly to handle bulk transactions. Your best bet is probably using "before insert, before update". Then, your pseudo-code would be:

```
Loop over Trigger.new
  Split on \n
  Set comment_length field to size of collection
```

By using before, you don't actually have to explicitly make a followup save call as long as you are working on the elements in Trigger.new. This context also lets you handle a trigger with more than 1 Task.

Comment: Not 100% accurate, "save for free" works only if you're in "before insert / before update" context. Attempting to modify it in "after" context will give you error that the record is readonly now.

Comment: @eyescream I think I had mentioned that, but perhaps something else I mentioned was off. No sense in using an "after" trigger when updating a field on the same record.

Comment: Very good answer but I have to give props to eyescream for telling me about the countMatches() method, which which drastically simplify my code in this application.